# Using sql statement inside if condition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, if-statement

```
int stageID=0;
if (stageID != 1 && stageID != 3 && stageID != 4 && stageID != 5)
{
    StageTwo();
}
```

I want to take the value of stageId from the database and display it in the condition of `if` statement. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok so what is the DB related code? There are many frameworks/databases/references/previous question to look at

Comment: I am using sql . If that your question

Comment: This is the sql statment I am using now I want only to use as a value what is in having . SELECT Topic FROM Kaiz GROUP BY Topic HAVING(MAX(StageID) = 2)

Comment: Please show us your existing **C#** code you are using to execute SQL.

Comment: the problem is not with execute sql . only I don't know how I can take a value from sql and put it inside if condition .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a `c#` code then you can use `contains` to check the `stageID`

```
if(stageID.Contains(1))
{
//your code
}
else if(stageID.Contains(2))
{
//your code
}
else
{
// your code
}
```

**if its a SQL code**

```
DECLARE 
   stageID number(3) := 100; 
BEGIN 
   -- check the boolean condition using if statement  
   IF( stageID < 20 ) THEN 
      -- if condition is true then print the following   
      dbms_output.put_line('stageID is less than 20 ' ); 
   ELSE 
      dbms_output.put_line('stageID is not less than 20 ' ); 
   END IF; 
   dbms_output.put_line('value of stageID is : ' || stageID); 
END;
```

**to get data in stageID from sql in c#**

```
try{
    int stageID  = 0;
    string strConnect = @"Database=Database_Name;Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog=Your_Db_Name;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
    {
        con.Open();
        con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(con_InfoMessage);
    }
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
    SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
    Conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
    if (DR1.Read())
    {
        stageID   = Convert.ToInt32(DR1.GetValue(0));
    }
    Conn.Close();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
// your exceptio code
}
```

do let me know for more help

Comment: This is the sql statment I am using now I want only to use as a value what is in having .                                                                                       SELECT   Topic FROM Kaiz  GROUP BY  Topic HAVING(MAX(StageID) = 2)

Comment: i have given you an example you can do that

Comment: BEGIN
 IF( stageID <> 1 &&  stageID <> 3 && stageID <> 4 && stageID <> 5)
  THEN 
   StageTwo();
 ELSE 
      -- YOUR ELSE CODE
END;

Comment: but I want to use it in C# . I know how I can do that in sql .

Comment: if(stageID.Contains(1))
{
//your code
}
else if(stageID.Contains(2))
{
//your code
}
else
{
// your code
}

Comment: do you want to get stageID from database?

Comment: yes! I want to get the stageID from the database

Comment: i am editing the answer take help from there

Comment: check the edited answer